# How to import variable from external module

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

I'm a backend dev who happens to be working with some Node.JS code. I'd like to use some of the constants from module [@aws-sdk/signature-v4](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/modules/_aws_sdk_signature_v4.html) in my code, for example `AMZ_DATE_QUERY_PARAM`, which is shown in the docs. I can't figure out a way to import it.

Things I've tried that all led to `AMZ_DATE_QUERY_PARAM = undefined`:

1. `const { SignatureV4, AMZ_DATE_QUERY_PARAM } = require('@aws-sdk/signature-v4')`
2. `import { AMZ_DATE_QUERY_PARAM } from '@aws-sdk/signature-v4'`
3. `import sigV4 from '@aws-sdk/signature-v4'; const { AMZ_DATE_QUERY_PARAM } = sigV4;`

Note that I also need `SignatureV4` from the same module, so, the correct answer would show how to import both. I don't really care whether it's CommonJS or ES6 syntax, although ES6 is preferred.

Comment: That documentation you linked is confusing. It doesn't properly distinguish which values/types are exported from that module and which ones are local declarations (or imports). If you look at [the](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js-v3/blob/main/packages/signature-v4/src/index.ts) [actual](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js-v3/blob/main/packages/signature-v4/src/credentialDerivation.ts) [implementation](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js-v3/blob/main/packages/signature-v4/src/SignatureV4.ts), you see that the constants are not actually exported.

Comment: Instead you'll need to import them directly from [the module exporting them](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js-v3/blob/main/packages/signature-v4/src/constants.ts), try `import { AMZ_DATE_QUERY_PARAM } from '@aws-sdk/signature-v4/constants';`

Comment: @Bergi That throws an error "Cannot find module /<path>/node_modules/@aws-sdk/signature-v4/constants".

Comment: Check your `node_modules` folder for what the structure of the distributed files in that package is

Comment: @Bergi Under `@aws-sdk/signature-v4`, there are `dist-cjs/constants.ts`, `dist-es/constants.ts`, and `dist-types/constants.d.ts`. I think I need `dist-es/constants.ts`, right?

Comment: ok, this works `import { AMZ_DATE_QUERY_PARAM } from "@aws-sdk/signature-v4/dist-cjs/constants.js";`. This doesn't, `import { AMZ_DATE_QUERY_PARAM } from "@aws-sdk/signature-v4/dist-es/constants.js";`, "Named export 'AMZ_DATE_QUERY_PARAM' not found. The requested module '@aws-sdk/signature-v4/dist-es/constants.js' is a CommonJS module, which may not support all module.exports as named exports. CommonJS modules can always be imported via the default export, for example using:"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my own question:

```
import { AMZ_DATE_QUERY_PARAM } from "@aws-sdk/signature-v4/dist-cjs/constants.js";
```

[This GitHub ticket](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js-v3/issues/2889) is also relevant.